# Creating a chat with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Good night !

I managed to show information about users and content of the messages with the following code

```
Route::get('chat', function(){
  // Get the number of days to show data for, with a default of 7
    $usr1 = 121;
    $usr2 = 123;
    /***Obtener conversacion 121 y 123**/
    $messageuser = MessageUser::with('conversaciones')->get();  
    foreach($messageuser as $msj){
        if(($msj->id_emisor == $usr1)&&($msj->id_receptor == $usr2)){
            $usuario1 = User::find($usr1);
            foreach($msj->conversaciones as $conv){
                echo $usuario1->name;
                echo $conv->contenido;
            }
        }
        if(($msj->id_emisor == $usr2)&&($msj->id_receptor == $usr1)){
            $usuario2= User::find($usr2);
            foreach($msj->conversaciones as $conv){
                echo $usuario2->name;
                echo $conv->contenido;
            }
        }
    }

    });
```

Now , I need to join this two condition into array to send the result to view , I don't know how to create this array , someone would be kind enough to help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try and use the MVC architecture that [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0) is designed for in order to help you organise your code.

If your variable values are within the MessageUser model then you can easily query them without doing your if statements. If your want to keep with you style of logic then you can easily loop using a foreach within the view and then echo using double curly brackets to echo the results.